# How can I search case insensitive in pgrep?

Tags: bash

pgrep uses regex as pattern style. I miss the -i option of grep, to tell pgrep, that I am searching case insensitive.

An alternative is

```
ps ax | grep -i PATTERN
```

But then I have to use the PID to send a KILL signal. With the pgrep and pkill combo I can use the same pattern for killing the app.

How can I use regex's REG_ICASE on the fly on the bash?

Comment: Why not use awk? `$ ps ax | grep -i PATTERN | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: The code is there, just commented out. Not sure why thought :-) http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/pgrep.c?view=markup#l627

Comment: Interesting. The code is commented out due to the -I option. FreeBSD seems to ask before killing. Hmm, I can't see how to use pgrep acceptably without the -i option. So, I think, I have to use the awk scenario.

Comment: Most process names tend to be all lower case; that's probably why the authors of `pgrep` didn't bother to support case-insensitive matching.

Comment: It IS supported on macOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
kill `ps ax | grep -i PATTERN | awk '{ print $1 }'`
```

Will kill all of your process matching case insensitive process using the magical `

Comment: If I may suggest so, grep is not needed here, awk can do the job of case-insensetive  pattern matching `ps ax | awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/PATTERN/{print $1}'`

Comment: You never need more than _one_ of `sed`, `grep`, `awk`, `cut`, `tr` in the same pipeline.

Comment: These calls don't ignore the process that runs the grep, always throwing an error for at least one pid.

Comment: Lol @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I was thinking the same thing, only I submitted it as an edit without the BEGIN section as `awk '{IGNORECASE=1} /pattern/{print $1}'` works the same.

Answer (score 8):

If the string is not too long:

```
pkill -f '[Pp][Aa][Tt][Ee][Rr][Nn]'
```

Answer (score 5):

[BSD only] 
[[FreeBSD pgrep man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pgrep&sektion=1)]
From the man page of pgrep: `man pgrep` under option `i`

```
 -i          Ignore case distinctions in both the process table and the
             supplied pattern.
```

So, we can just use the option `i` like following:

```
pgrep -fi 'PATTERN'
```

i.e.:

```
pgrep -f 'chrome'
echo $?
1
```

But including `-fi` option works:

```
pgrep -fi 'ChRoMe'
```

Output:

```
>   872
    910
    41391
    60087
    60090
    60092
```

Comment: what version of pgrep and OS is this? I don't see a `-i` option on my RHEL 6.8 instance

Comment: ```$ what /usr/bin/pgrep
/usr/bin/pgrep
        PROGRAM:pkill  PROJECT:adv_cmds-172```
This was a BSD version

Comment: and no wonder@BSD. That option doesn't exist in the GNU version. BSD would be worth noting in the answer

Answer (score 1):

As of "procps-ng 3.3.15+" pgrep/pkill now have a case insensitive option.

```
# pgrep --help

Usage:
 pgrep [options] <pattern>

Options:
 -d, --delimiter <string>  specify output delimiter
 -l, --list-name           list PID and process name
 -a, --list-full           list PID and full command line
 -v, --inverse             negates the matching
 -w, --lightweight         list all TID
 -c, --count               count of matching processes
 -f, --full                use full process name to match
 -g, --pgroup <PGID,...>   match listed process group IDs
 -G, --group <GID,...>     match real group IDs
 -i, --ignore-case         match case insensitively
 -n, --newest              select most recently started
 -o, --oldest              select least recently started
 -P, --parent <PPID,...>   match only child processes of the given parent
 -s, --session <SID,...>   match session IDs
 -t, --terminal <tty,...>  match by controlling terminal
 -u, --euid <ID,...>       match by effective IDs
 -U, --uid <ID,...>        match by real IDs
 -x, --exact               match exactly with the command name
 -F, --pidfile <file>      read PIDs from file
 -L, --logpidfile          fail if PID file is not locked
 --ns <PID>                match the processes that belong to the same
                           namespace as <pid>
 --nslist <ns,...>         list which namespaces will be considered for
                           the --ns option.
                           Available namespaces: ipc, mnt, net, pid, user, uts

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see pgrep(1).
# pgrep -V
pgrep from procps-ng 3.3.15
```